# is it possible to give step definition files from out side of class path i.e is from file system

Tags: java, cucumber

I want to load Step definition file to cucumber which is out side of class path like in file system can we do it.

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions( glue="D:/stepdefinition/"
features={"D:/featurefiles/" },//


    
        strict = true,
        plugin = { "pretty", "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter" } )
public class TodoFeatureTest {}
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Your path looks absolute. Did you intend to use a relative path?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje    Yes I want to load glue code or step definition  file which resides in file system. Can you provide some example code if it possible.

Comment: Ah. Glue code must be on the classpath. The JVM can only execute code on the classpath. Features can be anywhere.